# Проверка поля функцией filter_input

Tags: php

В документации написано, что в параметре options, можно указать логическое ИЛИ, я указал и почему не работает?

```
    <?php
if($_POST){
    $error = []; //массив для ошибок
    $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 5 || 30);

    if($age === false){
        $error[] = 'Возраст должен быть от 5 и до 30 включительно';
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Обработка форм</title>
    </head>
<body>

<?php 
if($_POST){?>
    <?php foreach($error as $error): ?>
        <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
<?php endforeach; }?> 


    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="name">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите имя">

        <label for="age">Возраст</label>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Введите возраст">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

ИЛИ работает с предикатами, не с числами

```
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 5 )|| $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Опции задаются таким образом

```
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => ['min_range' => 5, 'max_range' => 30]]);
```

> В документации написано, что в параметре options, можно указать логическое ИЛИ

Логическое ИЛИ относится к флагам, а не опциям, и

> Если фильтр принимает параметры, флаги могут быть указаны в элементе массива "flags".

Больше примеров http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php